# Dojo Issue: .parent() not a function

Tags: dojo

The HTML snippet:

```
<div class="hide_on_start">
    <label>Type of Visit</label>
    <div id="record_visit_type"></div>
</div>
<div class="hide_on_start">
    <label>Visit Date</label>
    <div id="record_visit_date"></div>
</div>
<div class="hide_on_start">
    <label>Staff</label>
    <div id="record_staff"></div>
</div>
```

The javascript I am using:

```
>>> dojo.byId('record_visit_type')
<div id="record_visit_type">

>>> dojo.byId('record_visit_type').parent().removeClass('hide_on_start')
TypeError: dojo.byId("record_visit_type").parent is not a function
```

I don't understand what the issue is with `dojo.byId('record_visit_type').parent().removeClass('hide_on_start')`. Can somebody explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres a couple of problems I see with your code:

I think what you are looking for is the `parentNode` property of the domNode you are retrieving.  This is not a method, but a property of the domNode you are looking up via `dojo.byId`.

Also, domNodes themselves to not have a removeClass method.  You probably want to use dojo's `dojo.removeClass(domNOde, cssClass)` method to do this.

```
var recordVisitTypeDomNode = dojo.byId('record_visit_type');
dojo.removeClass(recordVisitTypeDomNode.parentNode, 'hide_on_start');
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean `parentNode`?  Pretty sure `parentElement` doesn't exist.

Comment: Neh, the real problem is confusing Dojo with JQuery :)

Comment: Ah you are correct.  parentElement only exists in Chrome's JS engine.  I'll update my answer

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using `dojo.byId` as if it returns a `dojo.NodeList`, but it doesn't - it just returns a DOM node.  Only `dojo.query` regularly returns `dojo.NodeList` objects.

`dojo.NodeList` objects have a `removeClass` function (which operates on all nodes in the list), and if you `dojo.require("dojo.NodeList-traverse")`, they also have a `parent()` function which returns a new `NodeList` containing the immediate parents of respective nodes in the original list.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/NodeList-traverse.html

Answer (score 0):

parentNode is right but here is how you do it in dojo:

```
// Go from the DOM node to a NodeList
var myDomNode = dojo.byId('record_visit_type');
var myNodeList = dojo.query(myDomNode);

// Get the parent
dojo.require("dojo.NodeList-traverse");
var parent = myNodeList.parent()[0];
```

This method of calling dojo.query is valid:

```
//        Non-selector Queries:
//        ---------------------
//
//        If something other than a String is passed for the query,
//        `dojo.query` will return a new `dojo.NodeList` instance
//        constructed from that parameter alone and all further
//        processing will stop. This means that if you have a reference
//        to a node or NodeList, you can quickly construct a new NodeList
//        from the original by calling `dojo.query(node)` or
//        `dojo.query(list)`.
```

http://jsapi.info/dojo/1/dojo.query

It is like jquery $(myDomNode).parent().