# dojo get parent of present node in foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

In JQuery I used parent() function to get immediate parent of any element. In loop something like this

> $(this).parent();

The same I want to do in dojo my loop is like this.

```
dojo.query(".entryURL").forEach(function(node, index, arr){
        var url =  dojo.attr(node, "href");
        // I want to get the parent of node, which will be ofcourse diff for each iteration
      });
```

Someone please give me a Hint, I tried using parent.node also I'm trying to append to the parent like this

```
dojo.place("<span style='color:green'>URL</span>",query(node).parent(), "last");
```

I'm getting this error in firebug

> TypeError: _365.appendChild is not a function

### Regards

Aadam

Comment: A simple stackoverflow search (`dojo node parent`) bought me this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664781/dojo-issue-parent-not-a-function) .

Answer (score 0):

Some problems here:

1. `dojo.place()` or `dojo/dom-construct::place()` is not compliant with the `dojo/NodeList` API used by `dojo/query`. In stead of that use modules like `dojo/NodeList-manipulate` or `dojo/NodeList-dom`. Since you're a jQuery user, I recommend using `dojo/NodeList-manipulate` because it mimmicks the jQuery API.
2. To retrieve the parent of a DOM node, you indeed use the `parent()` method, but that part of the API is only available if you load `dojo/NodeList-traverse`.

This is a working example using the feedback:

```js
require(["dojo/query", "dojo/NodeList-traverse", "dojo/NodeList-manipulate", "dojo/domReady!"], function(query) {
  query(".entryURL").forEach(function(node, index, arr){
    query(node).parent().append("<span style='color:green'>URL</span>");
  });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/okk8unj5/